# How to take input and then display as output by 8086 dosbox assembly language

Tags: assembly, emu8086, dosbox

A total newbie for assembly language.
Here is my code, I am trying to get a string that the user inputs and outputs it.

```
    .MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 64 
.DATA 
    ARRAY LABEL BYTE
    MAX DB 20
    ACT DB ?
    ARRAYDATA DB 20 DUP (' ')
    
    STRING DB ?
.CODE 
MAIN PROC 
 MOV AX,@DATA 
 MOV DS,AX 
 
 MOV AH, 0AH  ;input string
 LEA DX, ARRAY
 INT 21H
 
 MOV AH,09H
 LEA DX, ARRAY ; output the string that user input
 INT 21H
 
 MOV AX,4C00H 
 INT 21H 
 
MAIN ENDP 
 END MAIN
```

This is my output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6c2i.png)

Comment: `int 21/09` expects a string terminated by a `$`. You need to put it at the end of input replacing the carriage return there. Also,you need to pass the address  of `ARRAYDATA` for printing.